# Kendo Multiselect Issue on validation

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly, kendo-multiselect

i am using kendo multi-select field in angular formly. In html file i am using  for checking error message. But for this kendo multi-select field. I am not able to find the formControl. for other fields like checkbox,radio, dropdown i am getting formControl. 
Is there any way to do valiadtion without using KendoValidator.Validate() function.
Any idea please help..

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz reproducing the issue

Answer (score 0):

here is the template for kendo multiselect field 
name: 'kendomultiselect',
        template: '',
        controller: ['$scope', 'formlyValidator', function ($scope, formlyValidator) {
        $scope.options.data.getValidationMessage = function (key) { return
        formlyValidator.getValidationMessage(key, $scope); };
        }]

In formlyvalidator service i have written custom code for error message, but this service is not getting triggered also.